# Converting CGPoints between UIKit and SpriteKit woes: UIViews next to SKNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

There are many posts on this but for whatever reason I can't seem to get the correct sequence of conversions correct. I'm trying to get the UISliders to go directly below the SKLabels.

As you can see in the pictures, one of the sliders doesn't show at all, and the other one is in the completely wrong place (the volume slider is near the seek label):

[image]

Here is my current attempt at getting this right, though I've tried a few other configurations that got me nowhere:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  let seekSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 15))
  let volSlider  = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 15))

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    removeAllChildren() // Delete this in your actual project.

    // Add some labels:
    let seekLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Seek")
    seekLabel.setScale(3)
    seekLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    seekLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + seekLabel.frame.width/2,
                                 y: frame.maxY - seekLabel.frame.height)

    let volLabel  = SKLabelNode(text: "Volume")
    volLabel.setScale(3)
    volLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    volLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + volLabel.frame.width/2,
                                y: frame.minY + volLabel.frame.height + volSlider.frame.height)

    /*  CONVERSION WOES BELOW: */

    // Configure sliders:
    let seekOrigin = convertPoint(toView: convert(seekLabel.position, from: self))
    seekSlider.frame = CGRect(origin: seekOrigin, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 15))
    seekSlider.value = 1

    let volOrigin = convertPoint(fromView: CGPoint(x: volLabel.frame.minX, y: volLabel.frame.minY))
    seekSlider.frame = CGRect(origin: volOrigin, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 15))
    seekSlider.value = 0

    // Scene stuff:
    view.addSubview(seekSlider)
    view.addSubview(volSlider)
    addChild(seekLabel)
    addChild(volLabel)
  }
}
```

Comment: What layout are you trying to achieve? Should the sliders be below each label?

Comment: @nathan yes, although at this point just having the sliders near the correct label would be a good start :]

Comment: HELL, I'd even take both sliders _being on the damn screen_ as a good answer :D

Comment: No problem, I'm working on a solution now. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close! There are two minor issues in your code:

**Issue #1**

You modify the `seekSlider`'s frame twice instead of modifying the `seekSlider` then the `volSlider`.

```
let volOrigin = convertPoint(fromView: CGPoint(x: volLabel.frame.minX, y: volLabel.frame.minY))
seekSlider.frame = CGRect(origin: volOrigin, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 15))
seekSlider.value = 0
```

should be

```
let volOrigin = convertPoint(fromView: CGPoint(x: volLabel.frame.minX, y: volLabel.frame.minY))
volSlider.frame = CGRect(origin: volOrigin, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 15))
volSlider.value = 0
```

**Issue #2**

The conversion code is not correct.

Using the `convertPoint(toView` method with the node's `position` should do the trick:

```
let seekOrigin = convertPoint(toView: seekLabel.position)
```

---

**Final Code:**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let seekSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 15))
    let volSlider  = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 15))

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        removeAllChildren() // Delete this in your actual project.

        // Add some labels:
        let seekLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Seek")
        seekLabel.setScale(3)
        seekLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        seekLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + seekLabel.frame.width/2,
                                     y: frame.maxY - seekLabel.frame.height)

        let volLabel  = SKLabelNode(text: "Volume")
        volLabel.setScale(3)
        volLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        volLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + volLabel.frame.width/2,
                                    y: frame.minY + volLabel.frame.height + volSlider.frame.height)

        // Configure sliders:
        let seekOrigin = convertPoint(toView: seekLabel.position)
        let offsetSeekOrigin = CGPoint(x: seekOrigin.x, y: seekOrigin.y + 50)
        seekSlider.frame = CGRect(origin: offsetSeekOrigin, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 15))
        seekSlider.value = 1

        let volOrigin = convertPoint(toView: volLabel.position)
        let offsetVolOrigin = CGPoint(x: volOrigin.x, y: volOrigin.y - 50)
        volSlider.frame = CGRect(origin: offsetVolOrigin, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 15))
        volSlider.value = 0

        // Scene stuff:
        view.addSubview(seekSlider)
        view.addSubview(volSlider)
        addChild(seekLabel)
        addChild(volLabel)
    }
}
```

**Final Result:**

[image: screenshot of sliders]

Comment: thanks!! can you elaborate on #1 though I don't understand

Comment: I just updated my answer. You probably copy/pasted some code but forgot to update the variable names.

Comment: xD XD XD arghhhh

Comment: you are going to need to convert your label height also since label height is based on scene points not view points

Comment: Basically a height of 10 points in the scene could end up being 12 points on the view

Comment: btw, nothing technically wrong with issue 2,  he is converting from scene coordinates to scene coordinates, which gets you scene coordinates.  You need to do that if your node is a child node

Comment: But the original code was inconsistent between the two sliders, so I thought it would make sense to simplify. You are correct though.

Comment: what infuriates me is that I did the toView initially but thought that it didn't work because i unwittingly had seekSlider twice